# How to handle async fetch undesired result?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I have the following React Native client code:

```
confirmMatchRecord(userId, matchedUserData['userId'], matchRecordData['matchRecord']['matchWinner'], matchRecordData['matchType'], currentUserRating, matchedUserRating, matchData['_id'], matchRecordData['matchRecord']['_id'], airbnbRatingValue, true, new Date())
.then((results) => {
    // Do stuff
})
.catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an issue with confirming the record. Please check your connection and/or try again later.');
});
```

And the following code in my `confirmMatchRecord` function:

```
export async function confirmMatchRecord(userId, matchedUserId, matchWinner, matchType, currentUserRating, matchedUserRating, matchId, matchRecordId, matchRating, matchConfirmed, timestamp) {
  console.log('Attempting to record match');

  info = { userId, matchedUserId, matchWinner, matchType, currentUserRating, matchedUserRating, matchId, matchRecordId, matchRating, matchConfirmed, timestamp }

  const firebaseIdToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@firebaseIdToken')
  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + firebaseIdToken },
      body: JSON.stringify(info)
  };
  const response = await fetch(ngrokOrLocalhost + '/confirmmatchrecord', requestOptions)
    if (response['Status']==='Failure') {
        // throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        throw new Error(400);
    } else if (response['Status']==='Success') {
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
router.post('/confirmmatchrecord', async (req, res) => {
// Do a lot of stuff

if (response==='Success') {
    return res.status(200).json({'Status': 'Success'})
} else {
    return res.status(400).json({'Status': 'Failure'})
    console.log('Match record was not confirmed successfully');
}
```

When response['Status']==='Failure (sent by server) it throws an error 400 as you can see, I was hoping to trigger the `.catch` in the client code then. But that does not happen, because the client code continues to run on the `.then` part.

How should I do this instead? Not sure if using `.catch` here is even correct or if I should do this type of work another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be aware of the bit of a footgun in the `fetch` API (I write about it [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)) where `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors, but your check is incorrect in a couple of ways:

- It's `status`, not `Status` (capitalization matters), and
- It's the HTTP code (`400` for instance), not a string

The `Response` object provides a convenient `ok` flag that's true for any successful response and `false` otherwise, so:

```
const response = await fetch(ngrokOrLocalhost + '/confirmmatchrecord', requestOptions)
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`); // This will be "HTTP error! status: 400" if the HTTP error code is 400
}
const data = await response.json();
return data;
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> My `response['Status']` was checking for a custom server message I had sent (`res.status(400).json({'Status': 'Failure'})`, I updated the post with it. Not sure why it didn't catch that

Ah! Okay. The reason it didn't catch it is that you're looking for it on the `Response` object, but your JSON is in the response *body*.

I suspect you don't want to use your own `Status` anymore since you know about `response.ok` and `response.status` now, but if you ever do want to include your own information in an error response as JSON, you *can* do that. You'd do it like this:

```
const response = await fetch(ngrokOrLocalhost + '/confirmmatchrecord', requestOptions)
const data = await response.json(); // Expects JSON in *both* the success response and the error response
if (data.Status === "Failure") {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`); // This will be "HTTP error! status: 400" if the HTTP error code is 400
}
return data;
```

But I'd stick with just the built-in `ok` and `status` for pure success/failure information. This could be handy if you wanted to provide more details of the failure, though.

Comment: Wow. That's a very nice write up written in a very simple way.

Comment: Wow thank you @T.J., I wasn't aware of a response.ok way to check for 200-299 status. It works now! My response['Status'] was checking for a custom server message I had sent (res.status(400).json({'Status': 'Failure'}), I updated the post with it. Not sure why it didn't catch that

Comment: P.S. Not sure why it took me days of googling to find this solution.. Why is this knowledge not common spread.. It really was a roadblock for my development speed

Comment: @beyondtdr - Ah, okay, `Status` was your own thing. I've updated the answer to talk about why that didn't quite work the way you had it and show how it could be made to work, though I suspect you don't want/need it anymore. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder One more question if I may. We now have !response.ok implemented and displaying response.status to the client. How would you go about displaying not only the error code but also some custom error message? I believe you would need to response.json() first on the Response object but then you can get problems if there actually isn't a valid response (in case of network issue I believe). How is this done in practice (i.e. how are different types of errors kept track of on the server and, if desired, communicated to the client)?

Comment: @beyondtdr - If there's a *network* error, the promise from `fetch` is rejected and you don't get a `Response` object (because there wasn't any response). So if your endpoint returns JSON whether it succeeds or fails at the HTTP level (your `res.status(400).json({Status: "Failure"})`), you can use the code at the end of the answer above to show more information.